# Error in setRepositoryConnection : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, ora-00900

Here I'm getting error while inserting the data to the database.

I'm not getting any error until insert statement in Oracle or after that statement.

```
package com.socket;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

import oracle.jdbc.*;

public class Message implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String type, sender, content, recipient;

    public Message(String type, String sender, String content, String recipient) {
        this.type = type;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.content = content;
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String Current = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        String Content1 = content + Current;

        Connection conn = null;

        String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";

        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.0.35:1521:orcl";

        String username = "itn"; //SET USERNAME

        String password = "itn"; //SET PASSWORD

        try {
            if (conn == null) {
                Class.forName(driverName);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

                String Query = "INSERT INTO ENTRIES (SERIALNO, TYPE, SENDER, CONTENT, TIMER, RECIPIENT, CREATEDON) VALUES ((Select max(SERIALNO)+1 from ENTRIES), '" 
                        + type + "', '" + sender + "', '" + content + "', TO_DATE('" + Current 
                        + "', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), '" + recipient + "', TO_DATE('"
                        + Current + "', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))";

                System.out.println(Query);
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate("Query");
                st.close();
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("error in setRepositoryConnection : " + t);
            //logger.log("Unable to set connection ", "Repository.java", "Repository", t, Logger.CRITICAL);
        }
        return "{type='" + type + "', sender='" + sender + "', contentx='" + Content1 + "', recipient='" + recipient + "'}";

    }
}
```

Comment: PreparedStatment can make your life easier.

Comment: Provide output of System.out.println(Query);

Comment: And safer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. Reading the error message helps in finding what the error is. Stop catching Throwable. That hides the problem rather than handling it.

Answer (score 4):

This part makes no sense:

```
System.out.println(Query);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("Query");
```

You need to execute query and with SQL you built:

```
int result = st.executeUpdate(Query);
```

The best approach is to use[PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), because it makes code more readable, easier to understand, it provides compile time check of paramaters and it provides protection for SQL injections:

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement();
statement.setInt(1, intVariable);
```

Comment: Oops, sorry. Will fix it

Comment: The variable name confused me